# Why concatenate HTML tags when appending to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I've seen this a few times before, finally decided to find out why.

Given this line of code:

```
$("body").append('<ifr'+'ame src="foo.html"></ifr'+'ame>');
```

Why are they concatenating `'<ifr' + 'ame'` and `</ifr'+'ame>'`?

Comment: Out of stupidity? Guess it could be to throw people of being able to scan the source for `iframe` tags though. Might get them round some security checks or virus scans perhaps

Comment: It is done a lot with iframes. https://github.com/search?q=ifr%27%2B%27ame&type=Code&ref=searchresults

Comment: Some editors choke on html in code, breaking it up makes the editors properly syntax highlight.

Comment: @TrevorDixon good fine. Wonder why though

Comment: What's weird about appending something directly to the body? that happens every time you create a jQuery UI dialog or open a jQuery UI datepicker. The only thing weird is the string concatenation, of which we can only speculate as to why it's there because it isn't needed.

Comment: @KevinB Right. The concatenation strictly is what I am referring to.

Comment: Sorry, i was referring to another comment which is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

Bit unsure if I should answer this question or not, based on the fact there could be many reasons, and only the writer would know. But here goes anyway...

The only reason I can think of (apart from just to be annoying) would be to prevent something viewing the code and seeing the complete `<iframe>` tag. For example, if I search the code for "iframe" I will not get any matches.

Now for the speculative part of this answer: why would anybody wants to prevent something from finding a matching iframe tag?

Here are a couple of options, as provided by myself and Kevin B via comments:

1. To prevent a process from scanning the code file and detecting an iframe tag. For example, imagine you have a content management system that allows HTML/Javascript but doesn't allow the use of iframes. Part of the upload process might be to analyze the code and look for the tag. The technique of concatenation used here would prevent that scan from detecting the iframe, and thus allow the upload
2. Parsing software, such as a syntax highlighter may have problems working with html mixed inside JavaScript, therefore adding the concatenation method would likely allow the parser to successfully identify the string as the string it actually meant to be

In all examples, it would be fair to say this technique may also be applicable for other tags that exist within a JavaScript string, not just the `iframe` one shown in this example